# problem on loading tensorflow models in django website backend in pythonanywhere hsoting

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras, pythonanywhere

I trained few tensorflow models and saved them using h5 extension.I am trying to load them in django backend in a view.All versions that i use are latest for django,tf and python.

```
models['1'] = load_model("static/car_model.h5",compile=False)
models['2'] = load_model("static/model1.h5",compile=False)
models['3'] = load_model("static/model2.h5",compile=False)
models['4'] = load_model("static/model3.h5",compile=False)
models['5'] = load_model("static/model4.h5",compile=False)
```

This code worked for me in testing.BUt when i try to host it in pythonanywhere
First i got errors on path as model not found.Later I tried to change path to

```
os.get_dir("static")+modelname.h5
```

After running it there is a error message saying could not load backend "Error code: 502-backend"
I am confused what to change and where is actual problem.please help thanks.

Comment: Please double check that the static folder contains your models from chrome inspector, for example.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: python anywhere has two links for error logs and server logs.In error logs there is no error displayed and in the server logs this displayed.here is link https://pastebin.com/bUUTZwxa. my static directory contains those models

Comment: From your logs, it looks like you try to use Nvidia GPU that is not available on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: what need to be changed  to overcome this error

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a conflict between flask used in pythonanywhere and tensorflow

But you can use theano librearies for keras this is is of any help. just configure the ~/.keras/keras.json. as:

```
{
"floatx": "float32",
"epsilon": 1e-07,
"backend": "theano",
"image_data_format": "channels_first"
}
```